# Input name com nome dinâmico

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

Quero criar um formulário com um número variável de inputs, de acordo com a quantidade de dados vindos de um BD e atribuí-los ao "name" nomes únicos.

Depois preciso submeter esse formulário e recuperar os dados via POST.

Pensei fazer algo do tipo:

```
<input name="nomePopular.'.$id.'"  type="text">
```

Mas não sei recuperar esse valor via POST.

Estou usando PHP e MySQL.

Obrigada!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Defina o nome do campo como array**

Ao invés disso:

```
<input name="nomePopular.'.$id.'"  type="text">
```

Troque para esse modo:

```
<input name="nomePopular[<?php echo $id;?>]"  type="text">
```

**Uma obervação, o seu código original**

```
<input name="nomePopular.'.$id.'"  type="text">
```

Parece haver erro de sintaxe na concatenação.

Não sei como está o restante do código mas, esse trecho que apresentou não faz sentido.

Caso esteja "dando um echo", seria algo assim

```
echo '<input name="nomePopular['.$id.']"  type="text">';
```

**No script que recebe o `$_POST`, requisite assim:**

```
if (isset($_POST['nomePopular']))
{
    foreach ($_POST['nomePopular'] as $id => $v)
    {
        /**
        Isso aqui é um teste com finalidade didática, ok?
        Vai imprimnir na tela o ID e o respectiva valor do campo "nomePopular".
        */
        echo 'id: '.$id.'<br />
        valor: '.$v.'<br /><br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Note que é possível omitir o `id` sem nenhuma perda de funcionalidade: `<input name="nomePopular[]"  type="text">`. O PHP irá popular o índice de forma incremental, contanto a partir do 0.

Answer (score 1):

Eu imagino que quando você diz "quantidade de dados", você quer dizer quantidade de colunas vindas do banco, correto? Se sim, talvez isso funcione:

Conectando no banco:

```
<?php
   define('DB_NAME', 'insira_aqui_o_nome_do_banco');
   //as informações abaixo são padrão, mas podem variar conforme você configurar seu banco
   define('DB_USER', 'root');
   define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
   define('DB_PASS', 'root');
   define('DB_PORT', '3306');

  $conexao = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

  if (!$conexao) {
     dir('Erro ao conectar no banco: ' . mysql_error());    
  }
?>
```

Depois disso, você conta quantas colunas o banco (no caso, alguma tabela que você escolher) está trazendo:

```
<?php 

INCLUDE "conexao.php";

$sql = "DESCRIBE [nome_da_tabela]";  //usando DESCRIBE, o banco vai trazer uma linha para cada coluna da tabela, assim você pode contá-las com mysqli_num_row
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
$numColunas = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
?>
```

Agora indo para o formulário:

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <=$numColunas; $i++) {
?>
<form class="form-group" method="POST" action="cadastro.php">
<label> nomePopular<? echo $i ?></label> /aconselho usar bootstrap para melhorar a aparência 
<input name="nomePopular<? echo $i ?>" type="text">
<?php
}
?>
<button name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Recebendo os inputs na página cadastro.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
for ($i = 1; $i <=$numColunas; $i++) {
?>
        $nomePopular . $i = $_POST['nomePopular . $i'];
```

}

Eu só não tenho certeza se esse último código pra pegar os valores do POST estão corretos porque eu não testei, talvez tenha erro de sintaxe, mas já deu pra dar uma ideia. Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Desculpe, não fui mt clara na pergunta. Eu quis dizer q eram as linhas da tabela (relacionamento 1:N) e não as colunas. Mas mesmo assim eu agradeço a sua ajuda.

Comment: Bom exemplo utilizando colunas!